# How to configure AppJS to work with node-http-proxy server

Tags: node.js, proxy, server, appjs

I'm trying to get node-http-proxy working with AppJS. Unfortanly it crashes on launch of the app. What I did:

- Download & extracted AppJS from http://appjs.com/;
- Installed node-http-proxy with npm install http-proxy;
- Edited the app.js window.on(create) function:

  ```
  window.on('create', function(){
  console.log("Window Created");
  window.frame.show();
  window.frame.center();
  window.frame.setMenuBar(menubar);

  var http = require('http'),
  httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
  // 
  // Create your proxy server and set the target in the options. 
  // 
  httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:9000'}).listen(8000);

  // 
  // Create your target server 
  // 
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
    res.end();
  }).listen(9000);
  });
  ```

When the app starts I want to start the nodeJS proxy server. Is it possible to connect from a external PC to this proxy server? (I know I will need to open ports for this)

For example if I run the app on my home PC and at work I will set the proxy settings of the work PC to homePC_IP:8000. Will this work?

Comment: Have you tried? Do you have reason to believe it won't work?

Comment: I did try, when I use locahost:8080 as proxy it works. When I setup a Wifi hotspot with my mobile phone on 4G and using my home IP:8080 it doesn't work, I did open port 8080 and port 80 on my router. Am I missing a step?

Comment: After some deep thinking I know why above didn't work :) I used the same PC where proxy server is set.... But I still can't figure out why AppJS is crashing when I add start node-http-proxy? The code provided here: http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/ does work but not for https :( Somebody has a suggestion what goes wrong with node-http-proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't got a fix for the crash of node-http-proxy but I instead I used https://github.com/TooTallNate/proxy and this works like a charm!